# How to mark email as unique key in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I am using `AWS Cognito` for `User Management` Below is how my configuration looks like

[image]

Now with this configuration, this makes email as mandatory & allow valid email address.

But I need to make email as a unique key.

How & where I can do the same in AWS Cognito?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Even with setting email to unique and as a sign in alias, it will allow users to sign up with the same email.

Once they confirm that email with the new account, that account will then be the one that gets logged in with said email. However both will still be confirmed, which was not ideal for my situation.

I implemented a pre sign-up trigger (in Typescript) to throw an error if a user with that email already exists:

```
import { PreSignUpTriggerHandler } from "aws-lambda";
import { ListUsersCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
import { CognitoIdentityProviderClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";

const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({})

export const handler: PreSignUpTriggerHandler = async (event) => {
  const {
    userPoolId,
    request: { userAttributes }
  } = event;
  const email = userAttributes["email"];

  const comm = new ListUsersCommand({
    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
    Filter: `email = "${email}"`
  });

  const { Users } = await cognitoClient.send(comm);

  if (Users && Users.length > 0) {
    throw Error("Email already in use");
  }

  return event;
};
```

You also need to give the lambda adequate permissions for the cognito ListUsers command. As a bonus, heres that lambda implemented in the CDK, but this can be done with whatever you're using. I'm not sure how this would be done with the console unfortunately.

```
const preSignUpLambdaTrigger = new NodejsFunction(
    construct,
    "PreSignUpTrigger",
    {
      entry: "ENTRY TO HANDLER ABOVE",
      timeout: Duration.seconds(30)
    }
  );

const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(
    construct,
    `UserPool`,
    {
      standardAttributes: {
        email: {
          mutable: false,
          required: true
        }
      },
      signInAliases: {
        email: true,
        username: true
      },
      lambdaTriggers: {
        preSignUp: preSignUpLambdaTrigger
      }
    }
  );


  preSignUpLambdaTrigger.role?.attachInlinePolicy(
    new Policy(construct, "PreSignUpLambdaPolicy", {
      statements: [
        new PolicyStatement({
          actions: ["cognito-idp:ListUsers"],
          resources: [userPool.userPoolArn]
        })
      ]
    })
  );
```

Obviously customise to your needs, but this prevents an email from being signed up twice.

The inline policy is used to prevent a circular dependency between the lambda and the user pool, which caused me some headache.

Comment: thanks @kieron, this worked form me. Can you add some detail as to where can one find details about this in the documentation. Some references to documentations would be helpful. In case someone wants to do further customizations to the script.

Comment: @fazkan Sure, heres some links:

- [Cognito Pre Sign Up Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html)

- [Cognito list users SDK command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/modules/listusersrequest.html)
- [CDK NodeJS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html)
- [CDK Cognito Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cognito-readme.html)

Comment: How to avoid duplicate emails in the UpdateUserAttribute action? AFAIK there doesn't seem to be an analogical pre-update trigger. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidKubecka depends where you're calling UpdateUserAttribute. I would just put a lambda behind an API that checks manually to see if the email is already a user that then calls the UpdateUserAttribute, rather than letting users do it client side.

Comment: @KieronMcKenna Yes, that's my workaround ATM. I was just curious whether this check is available natively at Cognito. Apparently, it isn't which IMO is an inconsistency - for the SignUp action, there's a pre-sign-up lambda trigger but no analogical pre-update trigger for the UpdateUserAttribute action.

Answer (score -1):

At the `Email address or phone number` section select the Allow email address, and now the email address going to be your unique key, at the required field the you still need to provide the phone email and name fields.

Of course in that case the username cannot be the phone number. But it is still required.

Comment: this is not the case, you can still have multiple clients with the same email